# What is the recommended class for representing a box?

Tags: c++, 3d, ogre

In Ogre, there's a class `Ogre::Box` that *looks like* it can support a three-dimensional box. However, this class is using a `size_t` data type for storage of its coordinates. Since [`size_t` is essentially an unsigned integer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550799/521032), it cannot handle negative numbers, and so using it for any real geometry is not possible. I know I can just keep a few numbers or invent a homebrew box class by myself, but what is the usual Ogre way of doing this? Also, I don't care if the box is using integers or floats for storage, it just happens so that it doesn't matter for the task at hand.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how would a box with negative dimensions actually look like?

Comment: @MihaiTodor: inside-out ;-)

Comment: @MihaiTodor, sorry for the confusion, by "dimensions" I actually meant "coordinates". The box with negative coordinates will be just on the other side of the (0; 0; 0) point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at [Ogre::AxisAlignedBox](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1AxisAlignedBox.html). If you are looking for a class representing a cube as mesh, you won't find it. However, there is a convenience class which creates an `Ogre::Mesh` for you: [Ogre::PrefabFactory](http://www.ogre3d.org/docs/api/html/classOgre_1_1PrefabFactory.html)