# Why sizeof(size_t) is not 1?

Tags: c, assembly, malloc, size-t

I was just wondering: since `sizeof()`'s return type is `size_t`, why does `sizeof(size_t)` give me `4`?
That is, when I `malloc(someSize)`, did I asked for `someSize` bytes or `someSize*4` bytes ?

I've been doing an ASM homework for two days, and I'm getting pretty confused now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You need to explain the underlying reasoning behind this question better. Why on Earth would you expect `sizeof(size_t)` to be 1??? This is entirely unclear from what you stated in your question. `sizeof` measures sizes in therms of `sizeof(char)`, so `sizeof(char)` is indeed always 1. But why would you expect `sizeof(size_t)` to be 1?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. The size of a variable is not correlated with the value in it. What you're asking is equivalent to asking why multiplying a number by any `int` isn't always equivalent to multiplying that number by 4.

Comment: This is a great question actually, to distinguish between the concepts of a numerical value, and the size of the type used to represent that numerical value.

Comment: The only time `sizeof(size_t)` would return 1 would be if `sizeof(int)` returned 1 (conceptually possible, but very unlikely), which in turn would mean `CHAR_BIT` is 16 (bare minimum) or 32.  All more hypothetical than real.  If CHAR_BIT is 8, then a if `sizeof(size_t)` was 1, you could not allocate arrays with more than 256 elements, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), `size_t` is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit (see sections 7.17 and 7.18.3).

> The `size_t` is an unsigned data type defined by several C/C++ standards, e.g. the C99 ISO/IEC 9899 standard, that is defined in stddef.h.1 It can be further imported by inclusion of stdlib.h as this file internally sub includes stddef.h.
>
> This type is used to represent the size of an object. Library functions that take or return sizes expect them to be of type or have the return type of `size_t`. Further, the most frequently used compiler-based operator sizeof should evaluate to a constant value that is compatible with `size_t`.

This was discussed in this post: [What is size_t in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)

And when you do `malloc(sizeof(int))` it allocates four bytes of memory dynamically. Don't confuse between `size_t` and `sizeof(size_t)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right: type != unit. Thank you!
Now I'm going out for some fresh air...

Answer (score 2):

You're confusing the number of bytes necessary to represent some value and the number of bytes necessary to represent *that size*. Or, as @Mat put it in a comment, you're confusing the type and the unit. `sizeof(T)` reports how many bytes (`char`s) a value of type `T` occupies. However, because some types can be quite large, occupying thousands or even millions of bytes (think large arrays), this value has to be stored using an integral type that *itself* occupies several bytes (`size_t`).

As an analogy, write out the number 10^100 (hypothetically), and then count how many decimal digits this number has. Write up the latter number (hint: it's 100). 100 itself takes several decimal digits to write out, but that doesn't affect how many digits 10^100 occupies.

Answer (score 1):

> why does `sizeof(size_t)` give me 4?

Because of `size-t` is of type `unsigned long int`, `sizeof(size_t)` will give the size of `unsigned long int` on your machine (on my machine--32 bit-- it is giving 4 bytes).

```
#include <stdio.h> 

 int main ()
{
     printf("%d\n", sizeof(unsigned long int));
     printf("%d\n", sizeof(size_t));
     return 0;
}
```

> did I asked for `someSize` bytes or `someSize*4` bytes ?

Answer is: `someSize`, because `sizeof` function determines the size of the *data type* (in bytes). Return type of `sizeof` is `size_t`.
So, you can say `sizeof` determines size of the *data type* (in bytes) while returns `size_t` type data.

Comment: `size_t` is not `int`.

Comment: ... and an int is not necessarily 4 bytes.

Comment: Alright, but if `X` is the return unit of `sizeof()`, how `sizeof(X)` can be different from 1 ?

Comment: The second part is wrong. `malloc(3)` never allocates 3*4 = 12 bytes, regardless of the `sizeof` any type involved. It always allocates 3 bytes. -1

Comment: @delnan; malloc(3) allocates 3 chars, not 3 bytes. A char could be 4 bytes.

Comment: @pburka As far as the C standard is concerned, "byte" means `char` by definition. This is consistent with the older, broader definition of byte as smallest addressable memory unit, although as you point out it clashes with the now-ubiquitous "byte = 8 bits". But then again, `char` being 8 bits is equally ubiquitous (I know of one embedded platform where it's not true, but POSIX requires it and many other platforms do it too).