# diffptr_t fortran with iso_c_bindings

Tags: pointers, fortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'd like to have a kind of diffptr_t in fortran with iso_c_bindings. The memory distance result must be a signed int.

```
type(c_ptr) :: start,ref
type(c_int) :: res
start=c_loc(my_struct%a)
ref=c_loc(my_struct%b%c)
res=start-ref
```

Compilation error:

```
This binary operation is invalid for this data type.
An arithmetic or LOGICAL type is required in this context.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do pointer arithmetic in standard Fortran. You have to rely on the processor dependent binary correspondence between pointers and integers.

Also, there are no unsigned integers in Fortran.

```
type(c_ptr) :: start,ref
integer(c_int) :: res

start = c_loc(my_struct%a)
ref = c_loc(my_struct%b%c)

res = int( transfer(start, 1_c_intptr_t) - transfer(ref, 1_c_intptr_t) , c_int)
```

There may be problems, if the pointer values are larger, than the maximum positive value for the signed `c_intptr_t`.