# strlen() in crashing .exe

Tags: c, string.h

```
int main()
{
    int LengthofWord = strlen('word');
    printf("%s", LengthofWord);
}
```

For some reason this code is crashing. I want to retrieve the length of a string ( in this case string) to use later on. Why is this code crashing?

Thanks

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I suppose that's interpreted by some compilers as a multibyte literal, it should be of type `int` or something like that, and gets implicitly casted to `char *`, which tragic results.

Comment: this does not compile for a start

Answer (score 4):

You have these problems with your code:

- This is not valid: `'word'`. The `'` symbol is used for single characters, for instance `'a'`. You meant to write `"word"`.
- The type of `LengthofWord` should be `size_t` rather than `int` since that is what `strlen` returns.
- You used the wrong format string for `printf`. You used `%s` which is appropriate for a string. For an integral value, you should use `%zu`. Although, do beware that some runtimes will not understand `%zu`.
- Your main signature is incorrect – it should be `int main(void)`

So your complete program should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t LengthofWord = strlen("word");
    printf("%zu", LengthofWord);
}
```

Comment: Why should it be size_t? What is the diffrence between size_t and int?

Comment: It should be `size_t` because that's what `strlen` returns. What's the difference between `size_t` and `int`. Well, they are just different things. At the very least, `size_t` is unsigned, and `int` is signed. And they may be different sizes.

Comment: You can't say or rely on that `int` is `sighned` or `unsigned`.

Comment: @haccks Yes you can. int is always signed. char can be signed or unsigned, but the other basic integer types (short, int, long, long long) are always signed.

Answer (score 3):

It should be

```
... = strlen("word");
```

In C string literals are put into double quotation marks.

---

Also `strlen()` returns `size_t` not `int`. So the full line shall look like this:

```
size_t LengthofWord = strlen("word");
```

---

Finally to print out a `size_t` use the conversion specifier "zu":

```
printf("%zu", LengthofWord);
```

A `"%s"` expects a `0`-terminated array of `char`, a "string".

---

Last not least, start the program using

```
int main(void)
{
  ...
```

and finish it by returing an `int`

```
  ...
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What does %zu do/mean? Also what is a size_t?

Comment: `return` is optional in `main`.

Comment: Not necessary to print `size_t` with `%zu`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Then I'd needed to limit my answer to C99 and above.

Comment: @alk. It is allowed in C99 to omit the `return 0` statement from `main`.

Comment: @haccks: On machines where `size_t` has a higher rank than `int` it is necessary, 64bit machine typically.

Comment: @alk; Yes. That's what I mean.

Comment: @user2955782: `size_t` is an unsigned integer type guaranteed to be able to hold the maximum possible size of an object that can be created on the machine the code is compiled for. `zu` is the conversion specfier `u` for unsigned, prefixed by the length modifer for `size_t`/`ssize_t` which is `z`.

Answer (score 2):

There is difference between `'` quote and `"` quote in C. For strings `"` is used.
Change

```
int LengthofWord = strlen('word');  
                          ^    ^
                          |    |
                          -----------Replace these single quotes with double quotes("")
```

to

```
int LengthofWord = strlen("word");
```

`strlen` returns [`size_t`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550799/2455888) type. Declare it as `size_t` type instead of `int`. Also change the format specifier in the `printf` to `%zu`

```
  printf("%d", LengthofWord);
```

Your final code should look like

```
int main(void)
{
    size_t LengthofWord = strlen('word');
    printf("%zu", LengthofWord);

    return 0;
}
```