# strlen function return type - c programing

Tags: c

I am pretty new in C programming and trying to understand it conceptually. 
I ran to the following function prototype  and other similar function prototypes

```
size_t strlen( const char *s );
```

I do not quite get what means a return type of **size_t**

Comment: Did you try: [google it](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=size_t)?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/ should give a hint.

Comment: its just an unsigned int size_t is equivalent to unsigned int.it is typedef.

Comment: @Yu Hao : I knew it is a decimal number, was not sure about it in terms of terminology

Comment: @Cgraphics all numbers are values, it does not make sense to talk about decimal, octal, hexadecimal, binary. Decimal is just a representation of the number

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is size\_t in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

`size_t` is basically of unsigned integer type. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) and [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/size_t/).

Answer (score 2):

It's basically an `unsigned int`

Consider the semantic as "A type that can hold a number big enough to store the maximum size of a memory chunk"

Comment: It's not an `unsigned int` at all. It's an unsigned integral type. So is `unsigned long` and `unsigned short` but they are not identical types.

Answer (score 1):

`size_t` is a data type in C. It is unsigned, and capable of holding integer values at least as big as the maximum size of an object.

So you will never "overflow" doing `size_t x = sizeof something;`, and it is the right type to use for an array index, or the argument to `malloc`.

Your `<stddef.h>` header defines it by a `typedef`, although this fact is not relevant to its use. You should write code that does not depend on what that typedef actually is.

Answer (score 1):

As per C99, at §7.17

> **size_t** is defined on **stddef.h** header file and is the **unsigned integer type** of the result of the sizeof operator. Also, the types used for size_t **should not have an integer conversion rank greater than that of signed long int** unless the implementation supports objects large enough to make this necessary.

Answer (score 1):

`ISO C11 7.19` (very similar in earlier iterations of the standard as well) defines `size_t` thus:

> the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator.

You can get it by including either `stddef.h` or `stdio.h`. It's not an `unsigned int` any more than `unsigned short` or `unsigned long` are, it's a distinct type, albeit one that can be promotoed quite readily to other types.

It's simply an unsigned integral type taking values from `0` through `SIZE_MAX` (defined in `stdint.h` if you want to use it) inclusive, guaranteed to be at least `65535`.

Some people actually persist in using `int` or `unsigned int` instead of `size_t` but that's not technically a good idea, if you want truly portable source code.

The standard states that, unless your implementation handles truly large objects, the conversion rank should be less than or equal to a `signed long int` - since it's quite possible for `signed long int` to be a *greater* conversion rank than `signed int`, you risk losing information.

Of course, you rarely deal with things of a size larger than `signed int` anyway, which is why you can mostly get away with it.

Answer (score 0):

size_t is unsigned int return type in c.

Comment: Example: windows 64 bits/Visual Studio: size_t is 64 bits, unsigned int is 32 bits.