# Insertion sort in C

Tags: insertion-sort

I implemented an insertion sort in C and someone who was helping me told my make something a pointer, as shown in the following line near the end, but why?

```
size_t size = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
```

Why is the second one a pointer to array, and what does size_t do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof(array)` = size, in bytes, of the entire array;

`sizeof(*array)` = size, in bytes, of the first item in the array;

As items in a C array are of uniform size, dividing the first by the second gives the number of items in the array.

`size_t` is an unsigned integer large enough to store the size of any item the computer dan store in memory. So, usually, it's the same as an `unsigned int`, but it's not guaranteed to be and there's semantic value in it being a different thing.

Comment: Already edited for `size_t`; `array[0]` would be equivalent. So it's just an arbitrary choice. Arrays are not plain pointers but can be used equivalently to them.

Comment: Alright, thanks. So `size_t` could also evaluate to `long long` or `short` or `unsigned long` based on the compiler and architecture?

Comment: Yes. The spec just defines it as "the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator" and for `sizeof` "The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is size_t". No other constraints are specified.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the second one a pointer to array

**Example 1**
char a[5];
sizeof(a)=5
sizeof(*a)=1

So, size = 5/1 = 5 // this indicates the no of elements in the array

**Example 2**
int a[5];
sizeof(a)= 20
sizeof(*a)=4

So, size = 20/4 = 5 // this indicates the no of elements in the array

> and what does size_t do?

Read: [What is size_t in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)