# what is the different between a-b ==0 and a ==b in python

Tags: python

this is the code.

```
import math

a = math.pow(10,100)
b = 10 ** 100
c = 10 ** 100

print(a==b)   # false
print(a-b==0) # true
```

I know the math.pow is not correct while the number is too large.  but how to understand the next point that a == b is not the same as a-b == 0 ?

my python version is 3.9.6 64bit

Comment: ```math.pow``` returns ```1e+100```. And ```10**100``` returns ```1000......```

Comment: [When does Python perform type conversion when comparing int and float?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52557054)

Answer (score 1):

This is because of floatingpoint error that can happen to large or small float number. See more info on https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Float numbers is stored as an 53 bit. So this problem will not happen to float numbers lower than `4503599627370496`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 for more info.

```
import math

a = math.pow(10,100)
b = 10 ** 100

print(type(a))  # float
print(type(b))  # int
```

We can see that `a` is an float and `b` is an int.

```
print(int(a)) # 10000000000000000159028911097599180468360808563945281389781327557747838772170381060813469985856815104
```

If we convert `a` into an int we will see that the number has changed and is no longer `math.pow(10,100)`

```
print(a==b)  # false
print(int(a)==int(b))   # false
print(float(a)==float(b))   # true
print(a-b==0) # true
```

If we try to convert both to int it will be the same as `a==b` but if we convert both to float it will work. That is because both numbers will get the same conversion error.

When we do `print(a-b==0)` this will be converted correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
math.pow, value type is float
a = math.pow(10,100)
b = float(10 ** 100)
a==b is true
```

Comment: yes. it is ture. why can't use a=int(math.pow(10,100)) to compare?

Comment: @pythonnoob You actually can, but see other answers about why you have to be carefull with bigger numbers losing precision

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers, the precision is low that is why one is `True`, the other is `False`, if you try with a smaller number, you will see that both will evaluate to be `True`:

```py
>>> math.pow(10,15)
1000000000000000.0
>>> 10**15
1000000000000000
>>> math.pow(10,15)==10**15
True

>>> math.pow(10,20)
1e+20
>>> 10**20
100000000000000000000
>>> math.pow(10,20) == 10**20
True
```

But if you look at some larger numbers represented by exponent:

```py
>>> math.pow(10,50)
1e+50
>>>10**50
100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
>>> math.pow(10,50)==10**50
False
```

If you try to convert it to integer, you'll see that the number just changes:

```py
>>> int(math.pow(10,50))
100000000000000007629769841091887003294964970946560
```

Answer (score 0):

For larger numbers (like you've used `math.pow(10, 100)`), `a-b == 0` returns `False` because of **[Floating point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)**.

`math.pow()` - Converts its arguments to `float` type

From the [Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.pow):

> **Unlike the built-in ** operator, `math.pow()` converts both its arguments to type float.**

`**` and `pow()` - Returns an Integer.

> **Use `**` or the built-in `pow()` function for computing exact integer powers.**

```
import math
a = 10**2
b = math.pow(10,2)
c = pow(10,2)

print(f'a: {a}\nb: {b}\nc: {c}')
print(a==b)
print(a-b==0)
```

```
a: 100
b: 100.0
c: 100
True
True
```

From above results, you can see what `types` they return.

Also `a-b == 0` returns `True` in this case since the numbers are small.