# What is the correct definition of size_t?

Tags: c, c99, c11, size-t

First of all, what do I mean, by 'correct definition`?

For example, K&R in **"C Programming Language" 2nd ed.**, in section **2.2 Data Types and Sizes**, make very clear statements about integers:

> - There are `short`, `int` and `long` for integer types. They are needed to repesent values of different boundaries.
> - `int` is a "naturally" sized number for a specific hardware, so also probably the most fastest.
> - Sizes for integer types `short`, `int` and `long` are purely implementation-dependent.
> - But they have restrictions.
> - `short` and `int` shall hold at least 16 bits.
> - `long` shall hold at least 32 bits.
> - `short` >= `int` >= `long`.

That's very clear and unambiguous. And that is not the case for `size_t` type. In K&R 5.4 Address arithmetic, they say:

> - ...`size_t` is the unsigned integer type returned by the `sizeof` operator.
> - The `sizeof` operator yields the number of bytes required to store an object of the type of its operand.

In [**C99 standard draft**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), in **6.5.3.4 The sizeof operator**, they say:

> - The value of the result is implementation-defined, and its type (an unsigned integer type) is `size_t`, defined in `<stddef.h>` (and other
>     headers).

In **7.17 Common definitions** :

> - `size_t` which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the sizeof operator;

In **7.18.3 Limits of other integer types**:

> - limit of size_t `SIZE_MAX` 65535

There is also a useful article - [**Why size_t matters**](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/programming-pointers/4026076/1/Why-size-t-matters). It says the following:

> - Okay, let's try to imagine, what it would be if there would be no `size_t`.
> - For example, let's take `void *memcpy(void *s1, void const *s2, size_t n);` standard function from `<string.h>`
> - Let's use `int` instead of `size_t` for `n` parameter.
> - But size of memory can't be negative, so let's better take `unsigned int`.
> - Good, seems like we are happy now and without `size_t`.
> - But `unsigned int` has limited size - what if there is some machine, that can copy chunks of memory larger than `unsigned int` can hold?
> - Okay, let's use `unsigned long` then, now we are happy?
> - But for those machines, which operate with smaller memory chunks, `unsigned long` would be inefficient, because `long` is not "natural"
>     for them, they must perform additional operations to work with
>     `long`s.
> - So let's why we need `size_t` - to represent a size of memory, that particular hardware can operate at once. On some machines it would be
>     equal to `int`, on others - to `long`, depending on with which type
>     they are most efficient.

What I understand from it is that `size_t` is strictly bounded with `sizeof` operator. And therefore `size_t` represents a maximum size of an object in bytes. It might also represent a number of bytes that particular CPU model can move at once.

But there is still much of mystery for me here:

- What is "object" in terms of C?
- Why it's limited to 65535, which is maximum number, that could be represented by 16 bits? The article on *embedded.com* says, that `size_t` could be 32 bit too.
- K&R says, that `int` has "natural" size for the platform, and it can be equal to `int` or to `long`. So why not use it instead of `size_t` if it's "natural"?

### UPDATE

There is similar question:

[What is size_t in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774)

But the answers for it doesn't provide clear definition or links to authoritative sources (if not count Wikipedia as such).

I want to know when to use `size_t`, when not to use `size_t`, why it was introduced, and what it really represents.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: As for your second point, 65535 is the minimum limit. So a `size_t` is at least 16 bits, but may be more.

Comment: *common definitions of `SIZE_MAX`* Note that *common*, here, even if it probably means *common in 1990* or so.

Comment: all of the limits in the standard are **minimum limits**. That's why the limit for int is 32767 but actually nowadays on most systems int's limit is 2^31-1

Comment: Why not read the standard, e.g. [object](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.15).

Answer (score 3):

> What is "object" in terms of C?

"Object" is a defined term.  The C99 standard defines it as: "region of data storage in the execution environment, the contents of which can represent values" (section 3.14).  A more colloquial definition might be "the storage in memory for a value."  Objects come in different sizes, depending on the type of the value stored.  That type includes not only simple types such as `char` and `int`, but also complex types such as structures and arrays.  For example, the storage for an array is an *object*, within which is an *object* for each element.

> Why it's limited to 65535, which is maximum number, that could be represented by 16 bits? The article on embedded.com says, that size_t could be 32 bit too.

You misunderstand.  Re-read the first two paragraphs of section 7.18.3. `SIZE_MAX` represents the maximum value of type `size_t`, but its actual value is implementation dependent.  The value given in the standard is the *minimum* value that that can be.  In most implementations it is larger.

> K&R says, that int has "natural" size for the platform, and it can be equal to int or to long. So why not use it instead of size_t if it's "natural"?

Because there is no particular reason that the maximum size of an object should be limited to the number of bytes expressible in a single machine word (which is pretty much what the "natural size" means).  Nor, where `int` and `long` differ in size, is it clear which one should correspond to `size_t`, if either.  Using `size_t` instead of one of these abstracts away machine details and makes your code more portable.

**In response to the update:**

> I want to know, when to use size_t, when to not use size_t, why it was introduced and what it really represents.

`size_t` is primarily defined as the type of the result of `sizeof`.  It follows that what it "really represents" is the size of an object.

Use `size_t` to hold values that represent or are related to the size of an object.  That is expressly what it's for.  For the most part, you can accomplish this by type matching: use variables of type `size_t` to store the values declared to have that type, such as the return values of certain functions (e.g. `strlen()`) and the results of certain operators (e.g. `sizeof`).

Do not use `size_t` for values that represent something other than an object size or something closely related (such as the sum or positive difference of object sizes).

Comment: *...there is no particular reason that the maximum size of an object should be limited to the number of bytes expressible in a single machine word...* So why not use `long` then?

Comment: @Gill Bates There is no particular reason that the maximum size of an object should be limited to even `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @GillBates because there is also no particular reason that `size_t` should correspond to `long`, either.  As I already wrote, `size_t` provides an abstraction so that your code doesn't need to know or depend on the details of your particular implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Depending on what compiler developers take a decision about which maximum size an object should have?

Comment: @GillBates, yes.  That's what "implementation dependent" means.  The standard gives a minimum for what a conforming compiler must provide, but the compiler / library developers choose.  Typically, that choice is governed by characteristics of the target runtime environment, but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Can `size_t` be bigger that `unsigned long long`?

Comment: The standard does not specify the size of `size_t` relative to other integer types.  In principle, therefore, it could be bigger than `unsigned long long`.  In practice, I am not aware of any implementation on which it actually is larger.

Answer (score 3):

> when to use `size_t`

Use `size_t` to represent non-negative indexes, and to work with values that could be traced back to a `sizeof` expression.

> when to not use `size_t`

Whenever a value could possibly be negative, e.g. when you subtract pointers. This is allowed for pointers into the same array, but it may yield a negative number, depending on the relative positions of pointers. There is another type `ptrdiff_t` defined for this situation.

> why it was introduced

Designers of the standard had a choice of introducing a separate type, or requiring an existing type to be capable of holding sizes. The first choice gives compiler writers more flexibility, so the designers went with a separate type.

> what it really represents

It is capable of representing the size of an object in memory, be it an array, a `struct`, an array of `struct`s, an array of arrays of `struct`s, or anything else. The size is expressed in bytes.

The type is also convenient for using for non-negative indexes, because it can represent an index to a structure of any size at the maximum granularity (i.e. an index into the largest possible array of `char`s, because the standard requires `char` to have the smallest possible size of `1`).

Comment: C compilers, and a substantial base of C code, existed before the C89 Standard.  Some existing code relied upon "unsigned int" being large enough to accommodate the size of the largest possible object; other existing code relied upon "unsigned int" being of a particular size which was useful despite being too small to represent the sizes of very large objects.  Requiring that "sizeof" always yield the same pre-existing type on all implementations would have required a breaking change.

Answer (score 2):

> Why it's limited to 65535, which is maximum number, that could be represented by 16 bits?

Its atleast 16 bit.

> According to the 1999 ISO C standard (C99), size_t is an unsigned integer type of at least 16 bit (see sections 7.17 and 7.18.3).

Why use  `size_t` ?

`size_t` is a type guaranteed to hold any array index.

`size_t` can be any of (and also can be anything else other than these) `unsigned char`, `unsigned short`, `unsigned int`, `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`, depending on the implementation.

And to use `unsigned int` or `unsigned long` in place of `size_t` ,reason is similar that they are not the only unsigned integral types.

Its purpose is to relieve the programmer from having to worry about which of the predefined types is used to represent sizes.

On one system, it might make sense to use `unsigned int` to represent sizes; on another, it might make more sense to use `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long`.

So using `size_t` adds the advantage that code is likely to be more portable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no (single) "correct definition". As said, it's implementation defined.

> I want to know, when to use size_t,

For everything related to `sizeof()` and `malloc()`. That is, the technical size of objects.

> when to not use size_t,

For normal (domain oriented) counting and numbers.

> why it was introduced and what it really represents.

It provides an implementation independent way to deal with sizes and allocations, ie it allows you to write portable code.