# Difference in the initialisation of character array

Tags: c++, arrays

I do the following for character array intialisation :

```
  char a[] = "teststring";
  char b[]={'a','a','b','b','a'};
```

While for the first, if I need to get the string length, I must do `strlen(a)` ....for the other string I should do `sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])`.

why this difference?

EDIT : (I got this)

```
char name[10]="StudyTonight";   //valid character array initialization

char name[10]={'L','e','s','s','o','n','s','\0'};    //valid initialization
```

Remember that when you initialize a character array by listings all its characters separately then you must supply the '\0' character explicitly.

I get that with char b we have to add '\0' to make a proper initialisation.

ANOTHER : 
Therefore, the array of char elements called myword can be initialized with a null-terminated sequence of characters by either one of these two statements:

```
char myword[] = { 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
char myword[] = "Hello";
```

Comment: for any one reading this :  I read that if doing strlen ..we shoud do size_t len = strlen(a). ref point in the note: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c.

Comment: I don't see a difference; `strlen(a)` gives 10, `strlen(b)` gives 5..

Comment: @Kenney : dun think that should be the case.

Comment: You can use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` for the first case also, but not the other way around because `strlen` relies on the terminating `\0`

Comment: @Bhumi - true; it depends on what data is defined after `b`...

Comment: The `strlen` function scans for a zero char, you even might find one after `{'a','a','b','b','a'};` but this can sometimes take far longer than 5 steps, sometimes totally fail. It's just *undefined behaviour*.

Comment: Of course, you shouldn't be using `strlen` _or_ `sizeof` with arrays of anything in C++.

Answer (score 6):

A string literal, like `"teststring"` contains the characters between the double-quotes, plus a terminating `char` with value zero. So

```
char a[] = "ab";
```

has the same effect as;

```
char a[] = {'a', 'b', '\0'};
```

`strlen()` searches for that character with value `'\0'`.   So `strlen(a)` in this case will return 2.

Conversely, `sizeof()` gets the actual size of the memory used.   Since `sizeof(char)` is 1, by definition in the standard, this means `sizeof(a)` give the value of `3` - it counts the `'a'`, the `'b'`, and the `'\0'`.

Comment: Very good and easy-to-understand description that also includes something about `sizeof`.

Answer (score 5):

`a` is a C-style string, i.e, null-terminated char array. The initialization is equivalent to:

```
char a[] = {'t','e','s','t','s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

`b`, however, is not null-terminated, so it's not a C-style string, you can't use functions like `std::strlen()` because they are only valid for C-style strings.

Comment: if however i do strlen(b) i would get weird answers? or anyway that that could be +- the actual length?

Comment: That would be undefined behavior, anything could happen.

Comment: You would get undefined behaviour.  Anything can happen.  In practice, `strlen()` will probably keep searching in memory past the end of the array, until it happens to find a character with value zero.   Which, regardless of whether such a character exists or not, means you have a problem.

Answer (score 2):

String literals are expanded into char arrays, but also include the terminating zero char. So think the

```
char a[] = "teststring";
```

as if you have types this

```
char a[] = {'t','e','s','t','s','t','r','i','n','g','\0'};
```

### A rule of thumb

Whenever you will use **`strlen()`** on a char array, **use string literals** its for initialization. The `strlen` function can be thought as a simple scan the terminating zero char (`\0`) counting the iterations needed.

### A word about sizeof

Even if sometimes used with parentheses, `sizeof` is an operator, an integral part of the C++ language (inherited from C times). In cases like `char c[] = "hello";`, `sizeof(c)` will return 6, which is exactly 1 more than `strlen(c)`, and you might be thinking: "lets skip that inefficient scanning for the terminator", but `sizeof` stops to be such "efficient" as soon as it works on pointers, and arrays can (and will) be used as pointers whenever required. Look at the following example:

```
#include <iostream>

// naive approach, don't do that
int myarraysize(char s[]) 
{
    return sizeof(s);
}

int main () 
{
    char c[] = "hello";

    std::cout << sizeof(c) << " vs " << myarraysize(c) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[online demo](http://ideone.com/aWOZCH)

Answer (score 2):

You can always write

```
char b[]={'a','a','b','b','a','\0'};
```

to overcome *"the difference"*.

Also note

```
 sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0])
```

essentially boils down to

```
 sizeof(b)
```

since `sizeof(char)` is always 1. Your formula is used for any other array element types.

Comment: Of course the 'boiling down' bit only applies when the array elements' sizeof is 1.

Comment: @Tive Which is the case for `char`, there's obviously no other element type in question here.