# Why (positive_integer < negative_integer) is getting evaluated to be true?

Tags: c, if-statement, strlen

```
$ gcc --version  
gcc (Debian 4.9.2-10) 4.9.2
```

In the following code snippet why is the expression `100 < strlen(str) - 4` getting evaluated as true?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[50];

    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("%d\n", strlen(str) - 4);

    if(100 < (strlen(str) - 4))
        printf("NOT POSSIBLE!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Terminal:

```
$ gcc so.c -o so  
$ ./so  
foo
-1
NOT POSSIBLE!
```

From experimenting a bit I found out :

1. the `if` expression evaluates to true for any positive_int, negative_int pair such that `positive_int < negative_num` (which is absurd) where negative_int is in the form of `strlen` function call (see 2.)
2. if we replace the `strlen` with a hard coded negative integer then `if` evaluates to `false` as expected. Looks like there's something wrong with `strlen`.

Comment: Because size_t is unsigned. You probably would write `if (100 + 4 < strlen(str))` to avoid issues with negative numbers, thus obtaining correct results.

Comment: See [this So post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) for more info about `size_t`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `strlen` has type `size_t`, `4` is converted to (unsigned) `size_t`, then deducted from `strlen`'s return value, and then the result is compared with `100`.

> **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**
> ....
>   Otherwise, if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned
>   integer types, the operand with the type of lesser integer conversion rank is
>   converted to the type of the operand with greater rank.
>
> Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or
>   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with
>   signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned
>   integer type.
>
> **7.24.6.3 The strlen function**
> ....
>   `size_t strlen(const char *s);`
>
> **7.19 Common definitions** 
> ....
>   `size_t`
>   which is the unsigned integer type of the result of the `sizeof` operator;

---

P.S. BTW, even in a simpler case, as

```
if (strlen("") < -1)
    printf("OK\n");
else
    printf("NOK\n");
```

, the output would be `OK`.

Comment: @SouravGhosh Perhaps it depends on the version of the standard. I have `N1570`.

Comment: So here `3` is an unsigned integer returned by `strlen` and so `4` will be converted to unsigned too. What about the result i.e. `(unsigned)3 - (unsigned)4`? Does the standard guarantee that the operation of two unsigned numbers will yield unsigned value only?

Comment: @owacoder Ok. I think I got it. The result of `(unsigned)3 - (unsigned)4` is equal to `(unsigned)(-1)` which is pretty large than `(unsigned) 100`. Is it correct interpretation?

Comment: @rootkea I updated the post to include " _if both operands have signed integer types or both have unsigned integer types..._".

Answer (score 4):

`strlen()` will return an unsigned value, so `strlen(str) - 4` will be unsigned number which is "very big", and it will be larger than `100`.

Try casting the return value to `int` if you won't deal with very long strings.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char str[50];

    scanf("%49s", str); /* specify size to avoid buffer overrun */
    printf("%d\n", (int)strlen(str) - 4);

    if(100 < ((int)strlen(str) - 4))
        printf("NOT POSSIBLE!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if (100u < (strlen(str) - 4))` would be better.

Comment: `100u + 4u < strlen(str)` is better for avoiding unwanted wrapping.

Comment: I'm sorry. I just realized it would not have the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

`strlen` returns an unsigned integer of type `size_t`. When subtracting 4 from an unsigned 3, unsigned integers will wrap to the largest representable number, thus always being larger than 100.

Answer (score 2):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.23.6.3, *The `strlen()` function*

> `size_t strlen(const char *s);`

the return type of `strlen()` is `size_t`, and as per chapter §7.19, (*emphasis mine*)

> `size_t`
>
> which is the **unsigned integer** type of the result of the sizeof operator;

and `100` and `4` are `int` literal, which is of `signed` type here, referring chapter §6.4.4.1

> The type of an integer constant is the first of the corresponding list in which its value can
>   be represented.

You're trying to perform an arithmetic operation (subtraction) involving a `signed` type with `unsigned` type, hence the signed type is getting promoted to `unsigned` type before comparison. Thus, the result is of type unsigned and the final result of the comparison comes as TRUE.