# C for linux not returing if value is negative

Tags: c, linux

have this small sample of code:

```
size_t value;

value = (size_t) strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);
if (value <= 0) {
     fprintf(stderr, "Value cant be 0 or a negative value\n");
     return 1;
}
```

When I run `./prog -1`, it doesn't fail with `Value cant be 0 or a negative value` which doesn't make sense to me. Am I missing something?

If I run `./prog 0`, it does fail, but not if the argument is with `-`.

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned type, so `value` cannot be negative.

Comment: Here some more details http://www.thecodingforums.com/threads/return-1-using-size_t.868206/

Comment: Make sure you compile with warnings enabled, e.g. `gcc -Wall ...`, then you get a warning for this mistake: `warning: comparison of unsigned expression < 0 is always false [-Wtautological-compare]`

Comment: `size_t` is an unsigned data type defined by several C/C++ standards. This type is used to represent the size of an object.

int - What is size_t in C? -  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Answer (score 3):

Type size_t is equivalent to unsigned integer (int or long). When you cast to size_t, it will always be positive (compiler should warn you about unsafe casting).

More about size_t: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t

Comment: Actually it doesn't, but I got it, used 'int' and it works.