# how can I get char array size in function (language c)?

Tags: c

```
char a[255];
void test(char* a){
    printf("%d %d %d \n",sizeof(a),sizeof(*a),sizeof(&a));
}
```

all of those don't get the real size of variable 'a';

Comment: You can't, the array decays to a pointer when passed to another function. You can get the size only within the scope of declaration (function-scope in the case of a local array, and file-scope in the case of a global array).

Comment: strlen(a); returns the size of the string, but not the whole array

Comment: See [How to find the 'sizeof'(a pointer pointing to an array)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot. You will have to pass the size as an additional parameter. Probably of type `unsigned int` because a size cannot possibly be negative.

```
void test(char* a, unsigned int size)
{
    // ...
}
```

Although it's the same end result, it would be even better to make your second argument a [size_t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c), because that's the convention.

```
void test(char* a, size_t size)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Or `size_t`, used pretty-much throughout the standard libraries for describing magnitude of object sequences.

Comment: @WhozCraig Good call.

Answer (score 3):

You should pass it explicitly along with pointer to the first element.

```
char a[255];
void test(char* a, size_t num_elem){
    /* do smth */
}

int main() {
   test(a, sizeof a / sizeof a[0]);
   return 0;
}
```

And `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]` gives you a number of elements inside array, note that this trick won't work properly with pointers but only with arrays.

Comment: It is worth noting that the `sizeof a / sizeof a[0]` trick works only in `main` function, as `a` is of array type, whereas it doesn't work in `test`, as the global `a` is shadowed by the parameter `a`, that is of a pointer type.

Comment: Yes, that trick should be applied only to arrays, not to the pointers.

Comment: More to the point, it "works" it both places, but once converted to pointer-to-type (such as the case of a parameter), it certainly won't "work" like you want it to. It has been the bane of many-an-engineer in such cases, since *both* cases will compile without error or even warning.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. `a` is of type `char*`, and that does not have associated size with it. This is why most of the standard library methods to output to a buffer have an extra parameter for specifying the buffer size (see [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)).