# What does "count" string method return when I give a empty string as a parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

When I tried this code on a python command line:

```
>>> a = "hello world"
>>> print (a.count(""))
```

I have as a result:

```
12
```

Someone know what is the meaning of this number?

Can I assume that it is the same as using the "len()" built-in function by subtracting a unit?

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in the below code

```
"Hello World".split("")
# returns ['H', 'e' , 'l', 'l', 'o', ' ', 'W', 'o', 'r', 'l', 'd']
```

This is how it splits the string
So, look it at this way `""` is the space or no space between each character in the string 
(including spaces). So start counting from before `H` and count on each side of char and space and you will understand why it was 12.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this helpful answer on the difference between `len(a)` and `a.count("")` too.

[Why are str.count('') and len(str) giving different output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192449/why-are-str-count-and-lenstr-giving-different-output)