# Why does count of empty string in Python strings return len(str) + 1?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

The `count` function of strings return the number of non-overlapping occurrences of substring. However, when I try to count empty string in non-empty or empty string, it does not give 0, but len(str) + 1.

```
>>> 'aaa'.count('') # it should have been 0
>>> 4
>>> ''.count('') # it should have been 0
>>> 1
```

What is the logic behind this?

Answer (score 1):

> That's because empty strings are considered to exist between all the
>   characters of a string; for a string length 2, there are 3 empty
>   strings; one at the start, one between the two characters, and one at
>   the end.

[original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40192499/13486592)