# Python `in` keyword gives false positivies

Tags: python-3.x

I've been using `in` keyword to check if a character is available in a **tuple** and ran into a weird result. I'd appreciate if someone could explain the last result below. Thank you in advance.

```
>>> '' in ('n','p','')
True
>>> '' in ('n','p')
False
>>> '' in ('n')
True
```

**Edit**

As explained in Anthony's comment, it seems I've mistaken `('n')` - which is just a string in parenthesis - as a **tuple**. Using `('n',)` worked as expected.

Comment: `('n')` is not a tuple, that's a parenthesized string.  you want `('n',)`

Comment: @ParaD you might be interested with this thread :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192449/why-are-str-count-and-lenstr-giving-different-output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One item tuple, remember the commma:

```
thistuple = ("n",)
print(type(thistuple))
```

output:

```
<class 'tuple'>
```

but:

```
#NOT a tuple
thistuple = ("n")
print(type(thistuple))
```

output:

```
<class 'str'>
```