# Understanding python count function

Tags: python

I am a beginner in python ,I came across a problem in understanding count fun in python.

```
txt = "hi"
x = txt.count("")
y = len(txt)
print("output for fun count",x)
print("output for fun len" , y)
```

The output for count is 3,Friends let know why I got the answer 3,how does it ended up with that value.

Comment: This question was already asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40192449/why-are-str-count-and-lenstr-giving-different-output

Comment: What answer do you think you should get instead? Why? Why does it make sense to you, to use `.count` in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Count function counts the appearance of value in the string
As much as I know. You are counting apperance of empty string. "" Appears 3 times, 1st time before "h", 2nd time between "h" and "i", 3rd time after "i". As much as I know

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it counts the “gaps” in the string. That is the number of characters + 1

Comment: But I didn't give any gaps .

Comment: You count the number of empty substring in the input. You can fit an empty substring between each letter (that is what I called gaps), and at the start and the end of the string.