# Split a string of positive/negative integers by space

Tags: c++, string

I have the following string:

```
1 -2 -8 4 51
```

I would like to get a vector with 5 elements, each of them corresponding to the 5 numbers in the string. Basically, I'd like to split the above string by space as a delimiter.

I've found a lot of questions like this on Stack Overflow but so far any of them is able to get neither the first "1" nor the last one (from `51`). 
My code is the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

std::vector<std::string> split(std::string str)
{
    std::string buf; 
    std::stringstream ss(str); 
    vector<std::string> tokens; 

    while (ss >> buf)
        tokens.push_back(buf);
    return tokens;
}

int main()
{

    std::string temps = "1 -2 -8 4 51";

    std::vector<std::string> x = split(temps);
    for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); j++){
        cout << x[j] << endl;    
    }
}
```

My output is the following:

```
-2
-8
4
5
```

As you can see, the first and the last 1 are skipped. 
I'm very new to C++ (I've been maybe too much used to the built-in functions `.split()` of other languages) but I can't see anything wrong on my above code. 
Can anyone please help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: err works fine here. I get `1
-2
-8
4
51` as expected...

Comment: [Cannot Reproduce](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cffe001aedf4e0ee)

Comment: What's your compiler? Works fine on gcc: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/RZOT5kbvHvPraz5b

Comment: Maybe this is a far catch but: print out a newline at the beginning of your program. Maybe you just oversee the first one. 

Another issue: You may get a different type back from x.size than int. Try to cast x.size() to int

Comment: I'm practicing on a [coding challenge website](https://www.codingame.com), but if you guys cannot reproduce I guess it's an issue of their compiler so I'm gonna close this thread. Sorry about that.

Comment: Furthermore: the size() operator gives back the type [size_t] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) which is unsigned, but j was initialized as a signed integer. Maybe that causes some trouble. I tried it with other online compilers and your code worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you showed works fine in general.  The output is as expected, so the problem has to be outside of the code you showed.

However, note that your `vector` will contain `std::string` values, not `int` values.  Also, you should consider using `std::istringstream` for input instead of using `std::stringstream`.

If you want a vector of integers, try this instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::vector<int> split(const std::string &str)
{
    int num; 
    std::istringstream iss(str); 
    std::vector<int> tokens; 

    while (iss >> num)
        tokens.push_back(num);

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::string temps = "1 -2 -8 4 51";

    std::vector<int> x = split(temps);
    for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); j++) {
        std::cout << x[j] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You could then make `split()` use `std::istream_iterator` and `std::back_inserter` instead of a manual loop, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

std::vector<int> split(const std::string &str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str); 
    std::vector<int> tokens; 

    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<int>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<int>(),
        std::back_inserter(tokens)
    );

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::string temps = "1 -2 -8 4 51";

    std::vector<int> x = split(temps);
    for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); j++) {
        std::cout << x[j] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And then you could make `split() be a template function so it can return a vector of different types depending on what you want from the input string, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template<typename T>
std::vector<T> split(const std::string &str)
{
    std::istringstream iss(str); 
    std::vector<T> tokens; 

    std::copy(
        std::istream_iterator<T>(iss),
        std::istream_iterator<T>(),
        std::back_inserter(tokens)
    );

    return tokens;
}

int main()
{
    std::string temps = "1 -2 -8 4 51";

    std::vector<int> x = split<int>(temps);
    for (int j = 0; j < x.size(); j++) {
        std::cout << x[j] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```