# What C type should I use to count objects in memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, types, size-t

Let's say I want to keep track of how many allocations my program has made, so I increment/decrement a counter whenever I `malloc` or `free`. Similarly, I might want to count the length of a linked list.

What type should I use for such a value? I think the worst case for "number of objects in memory" is *the number of bytes in the address space*. That is, my counter should be the same size as a pointer type. This suggests I should set my counter as:

```
void * num_allocated_objects = 0;
```

However, this looks like an unconventional use of `void*`! One source tells me I should actually use `size_t`: ["You use `size_t` when you are counting something, and are sure that it cannot be negative."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551647/229792)

I'm not so sure. [`size_t` is "used to represent the size of an object"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550799/229792). These two answers seem incompatible: I can imagine a system in which the possible number of objects is larger than the size of the largest object in bytes. Using `size_t` to count things in memory must assume that the largest object in memory is the size of the entire address space.

What is the correct, idiomatic C type to count objects in memory? Is it `size_t`, or a pointer type, or something else?

Comment: 1) Pointers are **no** integers and not for counting whatever. 2) You cannot do arithmetics on `void *`. 3) How would you test the pointer? Comparing pointers to unrelated addresses invokes UB. Said that: it depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to be pedantic about this, then you should be using `uintptr_t`, which is an (unsigned) integer guaranteed large enough to hold a pointer value.

Therefore, you could in theory count every single addressable byte of memory with it.  Not that you would, if you were counting *actual* objects in memory.  But at least that unreachable upper-bound guarantees your data type is large enough.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know about `uintptr_t` - that sounds right to me! Btw, why do you call it pedantic? What would you use for this purpose?

Comment: Nitpick: `uintptr_t` is only guaranteed to convert to/from `void *` without changing the value in-between. Theoretically there could be architectures providing different namespaces for different types, so the actual memory space could be larger than what `void *` and therefore `uintptr_t` can hold.

Comment: Well, maybe it's not fair to say it's pedantic.  It felt like if you're rolling your own memory allocator and had lots of these values floating around, a smaller type with imposed limits (such as `size_t`) might be better.  But for a single counter, I don't see a problem with choosing `uintptr_t`.  One consideration is how many allocations would it take to overflow your counter, and is it practical within your application's purpose to consider that an overflow might actually occur.

Comment: In which case @olaf your suggestion of `uintmax_t` would be the best available, but still not guaranteed large enough I suppose ;)

Comment: @jameshfisher: You should first specify the architecture. On x86/64, ARM, PPC, MIPS and SPARC, go with `uintptr_t`. On smaller architectures like MCUs, `uintptr_t` might be a wast of memory. Depending on the max. memory area and RAM space available, you better fix the max. count and use an appropriate fixed-width type.

Comment: @paddy: No. Although some think it is overly pedantic, but a good developer actually **does** think about this (and have an appropriate comment in the corresponding `typedef` in the source code to document it). That's why I indeed think your intro about being "pedantic" is correct, although I agree for larger 32 and 64 bit architectures (see my previous comment). But even on ARM-Cortex-MCUs this can be too much waste and 16 bits are sufficient (I'd use a `typedef, though and not rely on 16 bits in the code).

Comment: Yep, it's important to value correctness, which you clearly do.  And to be clear when type choices for a specific purpose may violate or impose limitations on correctness.

Comment: I would not use an unsigned value to count objects in memory. Ideally one would one to be able to track errors with negative values.