# VC++ 2015: identifier "size_t" is undefined

Tags: linux, visual-c++, arm

I am attempting Linux development for ARM, however VS keeps returning the error "identifier "size_t" is undefined" in every instance stddef.h is referenced. I have replaced the preinstalled file with other versions but to no avail.

Comment: It may require include stdlib.h which I understand also includes stddef.h as perhaps there is some define that needs to be setup first. Let me know if that makes a difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: The errors being given are all occurring in the libraries included with VS, not any code I have written up to this point. In my case, alloca, libio, stdio, stdlib, string, unistd, and usb.

Comment: I suggest you add additional details to your question along with a code sample that replicates the problem. The more details you can provide the more likely someone can help you.  Good luck.