# Meaning of overlapping when using memcpy

Tags: c, overlap, memcpy

I am trying to understand the function `memcpy()` which is defined in the C library `<string.h>`

Syntax: `void *memcpy(void*dst,const void*src,size_t n);`

I know this function is used to copy the contents of the memory pointed by pointer `src` to the location pointed by the `dst` pointer and return the address pointed by `dst`.

I am not able to understand the following important statement regarding `memcpy()`:

- When using `memcpy()`, the memory address should not overlap, if it overlaps then the `memcpy()` is undefined.

Another query is:
Is the value passed to the third argument of the function i.e `size_t n` always an integer value?

Comment: When the standard says that some behavior is undefined, it means this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior

Comment: Th man is telling you that the, if `src+n` address overlap `dst` the final data in `dst` can be whatever.

Comment: For `size_t` take a look at [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c)

Comment: Is it the word "overlap" you don't understand?

Comment: @Michael Walz Yes!

Comment: It's nothing about memory leak. If you use `memcpy` at overlapped addresses, you will only lose some data.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix the title into something more accurate. But also, you said that `memcpy` is found in stdlib.h which is incorrect. So I'm curious what source you are learning C from, as it seems to be a bad one. The proper format of memcpy is `#include <string.h> void *memcpy(void * restrict s1, const void* restrict s2,
size_t n);`. Copy/paste from the C standard C11 7.24.2.1.

Answer (score 14):

From the comments your problem is that you don't understand what "overlapping" means:

Overlapping means this:

Here the two memory regions `src` and `dst` do overlap:

[image]

But here they don't:

[image]

So if you have overlapping memory regions, then you cannot use `memcpy` but you have to use `memmove`.

---

**Second question:**

Yes, `size_t` is an unsigned integer type. The third argument is the number of bytes to copy, so it can hardly be anything else than an unsigned integer type.

Comment: I agreed a graph will be the best answer.

Comment: Nice graphics. Suggest adding comment about `memmove()` as an alternative.  Also that `size_t` is some _unsigned_ type.  With "`size_t n` is always an integer value?", some read that as "`size_t n` is always an `int`?" which it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

`memcpy` doesn't use any temporary memory to copy from **src** to **dst**.

Let say:

- `src` starts @104
- `dst` starts @108
- `src = "abcdefgh"`

Then **'a'** will be **@104** and **'e'** will be **@108**.

Assuming char as 1 byte then after copying:

- `dst = "abcdabcd"`.

As `n` denotes length to be copied, it should always be an integer.

To copy overlapping areas, you can use [`memmove`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) function which uses temporary memory to copy.

Comment: Why would a temporary memory area be required for memmove()?   One pointer compare will allow the copying to start at the appropriate end so that the source is not overwritten before it is read.

Comment: C does not specify that `memcpy()` nor `memmove()` use temporary memory or not.  They may, they might not.

Comment: Linux Programmer’s Manual   : 
       The  memmove()  function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest.  The memory areas may overlap: copying takes place as though the bytes in src are first copied into a temporary array that does not overlap src or dest, and the bytes are then copied from the temporary array to dest. @ThingyWotsit

Comment: @urvi_189 Emphasis on the "as though".  But it's not typically implemented that way in practice.

Answer (score -1):

*)
The main difference between memcpy and memmove is,memcpy works on the same string but memmove works in separate memory by taking a copy of the string.
*)
Due to this,overlapping happens in memcpy.
Let me explain you with an example.
I took a character array :

```
char s[20]="alightechs";
```

if i do the following operations separately,

```
memmove(s+5,s,7);  
memcpy(s+5,s,7); 



o/p for memmove is alighalighte  
o/p for memmove is alighalighal
```

because moving or copying both happens single byte by byte.
till alighaligh, there is no problem in both the cases because dest=alighte(7 is the number of chars to copy/move),
while memcpy i'm copying from 5th position,

```
alightechs   
alighaechs  
alighalchs  
alighalihs  
alighaligs  
alighaligh
```

till here there is no problem,it copied aligh(5 letters)
as,memcpy works on the same string,**6th letter** will be **a** and **7th letter** will be **l**
i.,e every time the string is getting updated which results in undefined o/p as below
at 6th letter copying,
the updated string is s[20]=alighaligh
so we get now

```
alighaligha  
alighalighal
```