# Can part of a string be copied onto another string in C? But the begin index for copying isn't zero

Tags: c, string, copy

For example, I have this string:

```
ABABcct
```

Can I copy

```
ABc
begin index = 2, end index = 4
```

...from that string?

Is there any specific built-in function that can do this?

I know `strncpy()` can copy a number of characters of a string starting from the beginning of the string onto another. But I don't think it can do what I have just described. As far as I know, its "begin index" is limited to 0.

Comment: Kindly show your research / debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you can use the function `strncpy()` with a pointer to anywhere in your string, not only a pointer to its beginning.

Example:

```
char *src = strdup("ABABcct");
char *dest;

strncpy(dest, src + 2, 3) // Copies 3 characters from your pointer src + 2 to your pointer dest
```

If you run this code, `dest` will contain `ABc`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! You are probably the only one who actually understood where my problem was.

Answer (score 0):

With `strncpy`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char p[10],s[10]="abcdefgh";
    strncpy(p,s+2,3);
    puts(p);
    return 0;
}
```

#### I know `strncpy()` ...  As far as I know, its "begin index" (as I call it) is limited to 0.

You knew it wrong. It's not about begin index or anything - simply you need to pass relevant `char*` in `src` and `target` which is being done here.
To add further clarification - most standard library functions which you are talking about never put a constraint of passing the pointer to the 0-th index. It doesn't matter which index you send - you can send 100th or 50th doesn't matter as long it follows the things expected by function (null termination etc).

<sup><sup>The code posted here is for illustration purpose - didn't include the necessary checks needed to use `str*cpy` functions.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 0):

While in your case the standard copy functions would eventually work, their use is not allowed when the source and the destination are overlapped, in which case you'll experience an UB.

For such issue the standard C library provide the function `memmove` designed to handle overlapped areas. It works as using an intermediate buffer to solve any overlapping problem.

see also [Meaning of overlapping when using memcpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43088070/meaning-of-overlapping-when-using-memcpy)