# What is the correct integer overflow builtin to use with the size_t type

Tags: c, integer-overflow

For example:

```
size_t x;
...
__builtin_uaddll_overflow(x,1,&x);
```

Would the above code correctly guard against integer overflow regardless of compiler implementation?

What I know so far:

- This [reference](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/systypes.h.html) states that `size_t` is an unsigned type.
- According to this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c), `typedef unsigned long size_t;` may be used to define `size_t`.

Is there a function listed at this [reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Integer-Overflow-Builtins.html) that will always be correct? Or will it necessarily depend on the specific implementation? If so, how could I programatically choose the correct function?

Comment: How about `size_t sum = x + 1; if (sum == 0) Handle_Overflow();` instead for a portable detection?

Comment: The [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) reference does not support "`typedef unsigned long size_t;` may be used to define `size_t`."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
size_t x;
...
__builtin_uaddll_overflow(x,1,&x);
```

> Would the above code correctly guard against integer overflow regardless of compiler implementation?

No. `__builtin_uaddll_overflow()` is not a specified C operator nor a C standard library function.  It restricts code to select compilers.  The functionality of `__builtin_uaddll_overflow()` is not specified by C.

Instead, simply compare against `SIZE_MAX` for a portable implementation.  It is portable regardless if `size_t` is the same as `unsigned`, `unsigned long` or some other *unsigned* type, even wider or narrower than `unsigned`.

```
size_t x;
size_t y;
if (SIZE_MAX - x < y) Overflow();
else size_t sum = x + y;
```

This works for the various *unsigned* types too - even narrow ones.  Use the same `some_unsigned_type` throughout.

```
some_unsigned_type x;
some_unsigned_type y;
if (some_unsigned_type_MAX - x < y) Overflow();
else some_unsigned_type sum = x + y;
```

---

When working with *unsigned* types at least as wide as `unsigned`, code could use the following.

```
some_at_least_unsigned_type x;
some_at_least_unsigned_type y;
some_at_least_unsigned_type sum = x + y;  // overflow behavior well defined
if (sum < x) {
  Overflow();
}
else {
  // continue with non-overflowed sum
}
```

In the case of `size_t`, `size_t` is *very commonly* as wide or wider than `unsigned`, although not specified to be so.

---

The above usually works with *unsigned* types narrower then `unsigned`.  Yet the `x + y` is done with `int` math then and unicorn platforms could then overflow `int` math.  `1u*x + y` or `0u + x + y` forces the math to always be done as *unsigned*, regardless if `some_unsigned_type` is narrower/wider than `unsigned`. A good compiler will emit optimize code that does not perform an actual  `1u*` multiplication.

```
some_unsigned_type x;
some_unsigned_type y;
some_unsigned_type sum = 1u*x + y;  // overflow behavior well defined
if (sum < x) {
  Overflow();
}
else {
  // continue with non-overflowed sum
}
```

Or in OP's + 1 example, to insure *unsigned* math addition:

```
size_t x;
size_t sum = x + 1u;  // overflow behavior well defined
if (sum == 0) {
  Overflow();
}
else {
  // continue with non-overflowed sum
}
```

Comment: It might also be useful to note that in most systems, one can use `#if SIZE_MAX <= UINT_MAX` (use unsigned int) `#elif SIZE_MAX <= ULONG_MAX` (use unsigned long) `#else` (use unsigned long long) `#endif` for code paths that absolutely need to know which of the three unsigned integer types suffices to describe all values of `size_t` type. One use case is to add aliases (macros) for compiler built-in C extensions for `size_t`-compatible unsigned integer types (and `ssize_t`-compatible signed integer types, too).