# How do I detect space in a string?

Tags: c, string, spaces

The question is to find spaces between the string. And if spaces are detected the next word should be printed in the next line.
For e.g "*This is C*"
It would be printed as:
*This\n
is\n
C*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char str[20];
    int a,i;
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    a=strlen(str);
    for(i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        printf("%s",str[i]);
        if(str[i]==0)
        {
          printf("\n");
        } 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How do I make this code work?

Comment: Use `fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin)` instead of `scanf("%[^\n]", str);`.  Follow with `str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;` if you want to lop off a potential trailing `'\n`'.

Comment: Use a temporary pointer?

Comment: the posted code is missing the statement: `#include <string.h>` to expose the prototype for the function: `strlen()`  Which, BTW, returns a `size_t`, not a `int`

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions: 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  2) when using the input format specifiers '%s' and/or '%[...]', always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer as these format specifiers always append a NUL byte and to avoid any possibility of a input buffer overflow

Comment: Use [`strtok()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) and give space as delimiter and print the tokens.

Answer (score 3):

Use `isspace()` function. Also, don't forget that in C strings are terminated by `'\0'`.

Look at [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/isspace) for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

In your program, make

```
printf("%s",str[i]);
```

to

```
printf("%c",str[i]);
```

as `str[i]` is character not a string and the format specifier for character is `%c`. `%s` for a string.

And change

```
    if(str[i]==0)
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
```

to

```
    if(str[i]==' ')
    {
      printf("\n");
    }
```

inorder to print a newline each time a space is detected.

And use a width specifier for `scanf()` like

```
scanf("%19[^\n]", str);
```

where `19` is the size of the `str` character array.

You might also want to check the return value of `scanf()` which is the number of successful assignments it did. In this case it should be `1`.

Also, include `string.h` header file to use `strlen()` and there is no need to include `stdlib.h`.

And as noted in the comments section, `strlen()` returns a `size_t` not exactly an `int` although basically `size_t` is an unsigned integer.
See [What is `size_t` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c) and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t).

---

Or you could use [`fgets()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and [`strtok()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) like

```
char *ptr;
if( fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin) )
{
    for(char *ptr=strtok(str, " "); ptr!=NULL; ptr=strtok(NULL, " "))
    {
        printf("\n%s", ptr);
    }
}
```

`strtok()` uses the characters in its second argument as delimiters to tokenize `str`.

Note that `fgets()` reads in the trailing `\n` as well. If you need to remove it, do

```
str[strlen(str)-1]='\0';
```

if the last character is a `\n`.

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. performs the desired functionality
2. cleanly compiles

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    int ch;

    while( ( ch = getchar() ) != '\n' && EOF != ch )
    {
        if( ' ' == ch )
        {
            puts( "" );
        }

        putc( ch, stdout );
    }

    puts( "" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'd prefer `putc('\n')` over `puts("")`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is having undefined behavior here

```
printf("%s",str[i]);
```

because `str[i]` is of type `char` and you are printing it using `%s` format specifier which is used to printf null terminated array of characters.

From C Standard#7.21.6.1p9

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undefined.282) **If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined**. *[emphasis mine]*

Also, avoid using `scanf()` for string input. If not used carefully, it can have the buffer overflow problem. You should use `fgets` instead.

Coming to your question:
`The question is to find spaces between the string. And if spaces are detected the next word should be printed in the next line.`

As I have suggested in comment, you can use `strtok()` to do this by giving space as delimiter. The `strtok()` will split the input string into tokens. A point to note about `strtok()` is that it modifies the input string by being broken into smaller strings (tokens). If you are okay with it then you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define BUF_SZ 20

int main() {
        char str[BUF_SZ];
        char *pch;

        if (fgets (str, BUF_SZ, stdin) == NULL) {
                perror ("fgets failed");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        str[strcspn (str, "\n")] = 0;

        pch = strtok (str," ");
        while (pch != NULL) {
                printf ("%s\n", pch);
                pch = strtok (NULL, " ");
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

After `while` loop, the content of `str` is not same as it was before calling `strtok()` on it. Though, whether to modify the original input string or not doesn't make sense over here because after breaking it into tokens it is not more used.

Your question says - `if spaces are detected the next word should be printed in the next line..`. If it is just about printing the words in new line, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUF_SZ 20

int main() {
        char str[BUF_SZ];
        int word_size = 0;
        int i = 0, start = 0;

        if (fgets (str, BUF_SZ, stdin) == NULL) {
                perror ("fgets failed");
                exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = 0;

        for (i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
                start = i;
                if (str[i] != ' ') {
                        word_size++;
                        if (str[i+1] != '\0')
                                continue;
                        start++;
                }

                if (word_size != 0) {
                        printf ("%.*s\n", word_size, str + start - word_size);
                        word_size = 0;
                }
        }

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This solution does not modify the input string but just parse it and if the space is detected next word printed in new line.