# How to get a mutable u32 pointer and cast it into an int pointer of C

Tags: rust, ffi

Let's say I have a C function:

```
void func(char *buf, unsigned int *len);
```

To call it in Rust, I declared:

```
pub fn func(buf: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_char, len: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_uint) {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Then I wrote another wrapper:

```
pub fn another_func() -> String {
    let mut capacity: u32 = 256;
    let mut vec = Vec::with_capacity(capacity as usize);
    unsafe {
        func(vec.as_ptr() as *mut c_char, &capacity as *mut c_uint)
    };
    String::from_utf8(vec).unwrap();
    unimplemented!()
}
```

But the compiler told me:

```
error[E0606]: casting `&u32` as `*mut u32` is invalid
   --> src/main.rs:...:28
    |
307 |                                  &capacity as *mut c_uint)
```

Why can't I cast `capacity` into `*mut c_unit`?

Comment: Please note, that `unsafe` in this case is not needed, because to cast something into a pointer is totaly safe, but dereferencing a pointer is unsafe.

Comment: Second note: you should accept a `size_t` instead of a `unsigned int` for sizes (of arrays) in C. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: Third note: you have to use `#[no_mangle]` to disable name-mangling to be able to call it from C.

Comment: Fourth note: I suspect, that you want to modify the `vec` in the `func` function. Make sure, that you use `set_len` (which is unsafe) to set the length of the `Vec`.

Comment: @hellow Thanks man. For the second one: actually I need uint32_t here, but I do not want to include too much headers like `stdint.h` into the api header. `size_t` may be long, which is longer than uint32_t, not fit.

Comment: @hellow  For first one: I will try. For 3rd: yeah I did something similar. For 4th: yeah I did.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out I have to make the reference mutable.

```
func(vec.as_ptr() as *mut c_char, &mut capacity as *mut c_uint)
```