# Building strcat without the library and without pointers

Tags: c, strcat, string.h

I have been asked to build the [strcat](/questions/tagged/strcat) from [string.h](/questions/tagged/string.h) without using the library and pointers.

I have this so far but somehow it doesn't work:

```
void strcatO(char a[], char b[])
{
    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
    {
        a[strlen(a) + i + 1] = b[i];
    }

    printf("%s", a);
}
```

Output:

[image: a]

Comment: Note that when you declare an argument like `char a[]`, what the compiler really treats it as is `char *a`. So no, you're not doing it without pointers.

Comment: Guess you are right

Comment: `strlen()` *is* from the library. And both `a` and `b` *are*, indeed, pointers, even if their declaration looks like arrays. Actually, if your teacher tells you they aren't, ask him to explain why `sizeof( a )` in your `strcat()` will *always* be equal to `sizeof( char * )`, no matter how large the array in the *calling* function is. Bottom line, since *any* array you use as an argument to a function call *will* degenerate into a pointer, your teacher did his / her students a disservice phrasing the task like that. The answer is, "it cannot be done, all I can do is writing it without `*`."

Comment: I built the strlen beforehand in another function, and the pointers thing I get it now thanks!!

Comment: @DevSolar is correct. Arrays passed as arguments to functions are *always* "adjusted", as the technical term is, to pointers to their first elements. The declarations `void f(int arr[]);`  and  `void f(int *arr);` are the same thing; they are interchangeable. Even `void f(int arr[5]);` does not make a difference; the index is ignored. If you find the semantic and notational idiosyncrasies of C confusing you are not alone.

Comment: "I built the strlen beforehand in another function,..." can have a bad effect with this code.  Say the `b` string is length `N`. then `for(i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
    { ... }` calls OP's `strlen(N)` N times.  Each call running down `b` to find the length or `N` operations.  Being OP's code, a compiler likely will not recognize this inefficiency and then make this code `O(N*N)`  - very slow.  Instead call `strlen(b)` before the loop or simply use `for(i = 0; b[i]; ++i)`.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: In `void f(int arr[5]);`, it is not clear that the array length is ignored. Some compilers evaluate the array size expression (after which the value is discarded). For example, with Apple LLVM 10.0.0 clang-1000.11.45.5, `void f(int arr[printf("Hello, world.\n")]) {} int main(void) { f(0); }` prints “Hello, world.”

Answer (score 2):

out of your problems you continuously compute *strlen* for nothing hoping the compiler will optimize, you can do that :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void strcatO(char a[], char b[])
{
   size_t i = strlen(a);
   size_t j;

    for (j = 0; b[j] != 0; ++j)
    {
        a[i++] = b[j];
    }

    a[i] = 0;

    printf("%s\n", a);
}

int main()
{
  char a[20] = "aze";
  char b[] = "rtyu";
  strcatO(a,b);
  return 0;
}
```

Execution :

```
azertyu
```

Note that `char a[]` for a parameter is exactly `char *`, *without pointers* is false ;-)

---

and to point to the problems in your code as requested by  Eric Postpischil :

- `a[strlen(a) + i + 1]` writes 1 character after the right position, must be `a[strlen(a) + 1] = 0; a[strlen(a)] = b[j];`. In a way it is a chance else you will write more far after the end because *strlen* will not returns the initial length of *a* but an undefined value because of the probable missing null character in the rest of *a*
- after the copy you miss to add the null character

Comment: Your answer is awesome thanks!! haven't learned about size_t yet so I don't quite understand but I did get what you did thank you

Comment: @LidorCohen `size_t` is the type of the value return by _strlen_ and other functions, look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: This answer fails to state what was wrong with the original code or why the new code fixes it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did, but the initial code was so bad I supposed useless ^^

Comment: @EricPostpischil you are right, I tend to think "hide this code that I can not see" from a certain level of problem, giving an other code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187365/discussion-between-chux-and-bruno).

Answer (score 2):

> somehow it doesn't work

`a[strlen(a) + i + 1] = b[i];` appends characters *after*  `a`'s *null character*.

```
void strcatO(char a[], char b[]) {
    int i = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i) {
      a[strlen(a) + i + 1] = b[i];  // Oops: appending position is off-by-one
    }
    printf("%s", a);
}
```

`strcatO("ab", "cd")` will populate `a` as `'a'`, `'b'`, `'\0'`, `'c'`, `'d'`.

Printing that with `printf("%s", a);` only prints `'a'`, `'b'`.

---

To fix, code needs to append in the right position, yet this overwrites the original `a` *null character*.  Thus calls to `strlen(a)` are bad.

Instead, and to [improve efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378372/building-strcat-without-the-library-and-without-pointers/54379645#comment95572497_54378372), do not call `strlen()` repeatedly.

```
void strcatO(char a[], const char b[]) {
  size_t ai = 0;
  while (a[ai]) {       // go to end of a
    ai++;
  }

  size_t bi = 0;
  while (b[bi]) {        // while not at the end of b ...
    a[ai++] = b[bi++];
  }

  a[ai] = '\0';
  printf("<%s>", a);
}
```

---

Details of subtle improvements:

`const` in `const char b[]` implies `b` references data that this function should not attempt to change.  This 1) allows this function to concatenate `b` should it be a `const char []` 2) Allows optimizations a weak compiler may not see.

`size_t` is better than `int` for *long* strings which could be longer than `INT_MAX`.  `size_t` is the "right size" type for string lengths and array sizing.  OP (Original Poster) did have "without using the library" and `size_t` is from the library, so code could use `unsigned` or better `unsigned long` as  alternatives.

Comment: I think the OP has written a strlen function ;-).

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider yes OP computes the length of b, but lost it ^^ Btw, what means _OP_ ? I use it because some do, but without knowing exactely what that acronyms means ^^

Comment: @bruno: "Original Poster".

Comment: @bruno Either original post or original poster, as far as I know, at least that's how I use it.

Comment: By the way, I like this answer because it  explains the issue very clearly, and the solution  is concise and correct.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider strangely I prefer my old one ^^

Comment: Nicely done. If this answer had been here earlier, I would not have written mine.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
a[strlen(a) + i + 1] = b[i];
```

writes characters one position further than you want.

When called in your example, your routine is passed `a` and `b` with these contents:

```
a[0] = 'e'
a[1] = 'g'
a[2] = 'g'
a[3] = 0

b[0] = 's'
b[1] = 'a'
b[2] = 'm'
b[3] = 'p'
b[4] = 'l'
b[5] = 'e'
b[6] = 0
```

You want to produce this result:

```
a[0] = 'e'
a[1] = 'g'
a[2] = 'g'
a[3] = 's'
a[4] = 'a'
a[5] = 'm'
a[6] = 'p'
a[7] = 'l'
a[8] = 'e'
a[9] = 0
```

However, since your code writes to `a[strlen(a) + i + 1]`, it writes the first character to `a[strlen(a) + 0 + 1]`, which is `a[4]`. You want it in `a[3]`. You could change `strlen(a) + i + 1` to `strlen(a) + i`, but then, when you have written the first character, you will have overwritten the null terminating character, and `strlen` will not work to find the length anymore. To fix this, you can remember the length of `a` before entering the loop. Consider this code:

```
int i = 0;
int LengthOfA = strlen(a);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
{
    a[LengthOfA + i] = b[i];
}
```

That will write the characters to the correct place.

However, it does not put a null terminating character at the end of `a`. To do that, we can put another statement after the loop:

```
a[LengthOfA + i] = 0;
```

At that point, your routine will work for normal situations. However, there are two more improvements we can make.

First, instead of using `int` for lengths and indices, we can use `size_t`. In C, the width of `int` is flexible, and `size_t` is provided as a good type to use when dealing with sizes of objects. To use it, first use `#include <stddef.h>` to get its definition. Then your code can be:

```
size_t i = 0;
size_t LengthOfA = strlen(a);
for (i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
{
    a[LengthOfA + i] = b[i];
}
a[LengthOfA + i] = 0;
```

Second, your code nominally calculates `strlen(b)` in every iteration. This is wasteful. It is preferable to calculate the length once and remember it:

```
size_t i = 0;
size_t LengthOfA = strlen(a);
size_t LengthOfB = strlen(b);
for (i = 0; i < LengthOfB; ++i)
{
    a[LengthOfA + i] = b[i];
}
a[LengthOfA + i] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not overwriting the first string *null*(`\0`) terminator

```
    a[strlen(a) + i + 1] = b[i];
```

should be

```
int len = strlen(a);

for(i = 0; i < strlen(b); ++i)
{
    a[len + i] = b[i];
}
a[len+i] = '\0'; //Finally null terminate the new string.
```

Comment: ![a](https://i.gyazo.com/358a49e1bbbc7f7f0b8aacfe6022758e.png)
This is the new output, the overall size of the array 'a' is 25

Comment: Given OP wrote their own `strlen()`, this code suffers the same [O(N*N) inefficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54378372/c-building-strcat-without-the-library-and-without-pointers#comment95572497_54378372).  No need to repeatedly call `strlen(b)`.

Comment: This answer fails to state what was wrong with the original code or why the new code fixes it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil This does does state a key problem with "You are not overwriting the first string null", which at least is a partial explanation.