# c++ casting for different targets (compilers)

Tags: c++, casting, cross-compiling

Given the following:

[code-link](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Ob6VIkOx9XRqkIlC)

Here is the code itself for convenience (and I am not sure my link is working):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdint.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout<<"Hello World";
    std::vector<std::string> test_vect {"1", "2"};
    long unsigned int size = static_cast<long unsigned int>(test_vect.size());

    std::cout << "size: " << size << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the following compile options: `g++ file.c -Wall -Wextra "-Werror" "-Wuseless-cast"`

You can see here that I am casting `vector.size()` to `long unsigned int`, this gets flagged up as a useless cast on Wandbox (my link) however the same code running on my linux box does not give a warning - but it will give me a different warning if I **dont** cast it.

I understand that the two `unsigned long` vs `size_t` can be different. But what I am trying to do is write some code that has no warnings with all the casting warnings set (maybe this is optamisitic when cross compiling).

So, one compiler complains that I am converting types, so I cast, but then another compiler is complaining about useless cast - so I remove the cast - and around we go :(

Is there a good approach to this so that I dont get warnings on either compilers?

I was going to just remove the `-Wuseless-cast` option, but I thought I would see if anyone has other ideas...

Comment: seems you will need an old good #ifdef

Comment: To be honest `-Wuseless-cast` doesn't seem useful to me. I'd remove it.

Comment: Ok you have provided MCVE, but it would be nice to see in what context your code does that cast, since it may open doors for other fixes.

Comment: Instead of trying to store the size of the vector in an `long unsigned int`,  use a `std::size_t`.   That stores the result in a variable of the appropriate type, and eliminates the need for casting at all.

Comment: @P.PICARD It is a way around it : )  ... but I could forsee that getting annoying with more and more code...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yeah, I think I am starting to come to that conclusion too

Comment: _"Here is the code itself for convenience"_ Not just convenience; the question _must_ be self-contained for posterity

Comment: @Peter the only issue with that is that we have an API that takes a `long unsigned` (well, that is just one example of the issue) - so we can't really change that part so we would have to do a conversion somewhere..

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ... true, I guess wandox might die one day :o

Comment: Or stop storing your code. Doesn't matter. If we put the MCVE here, there is assuredly no problem.

Comment: @code_fodder - Your example is contrived, since that means a flawed API (if the API is intended to be cross-platform, using `unsigned long` to hold the size of a vector or the result of `sizeof` is a flaw). In any event, the obvious solution would be to change the API - if it's not in your control, submit a feature/bug request.  If  you can't (or, as the owner of the API, you arbitrarily won't) do that, then write a function to do the conversion. That isolates the conversion into one place, and you can use the preprocessor to help implement versions of that function for different compilers.

Comment: Also possible would be to use `auto size = test_vect.size()` or `decltype(test_vect.size()) size = test_vect.size()`.

Comment: @nada Pointless. We already know what the return type is. It's `std::size_t`, always. All you've done is to mask that.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Masking makes compiler happy, which is what code_fodder wants

Comment: @nada That's changing the type of the variable which has been suggested already. Masking that change achieves nothing but confusion

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit How is `std::size_t` different? Isn't that also masking?

Comment: @nada: No. It clearly shows what the type is. It's `std::size_t`. When you write `auto` instead, you've _masked what that is_ because you can no longer find out the type by reading that bit of code. For no gain.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit True, but std::size_t is also just a mask for `unsigned long long int` on most, if not all systems.

Comment: @nada No, it's a distinct type with specific semantics.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I am not sure what that means, but I guess you are correct.

Comment: @nada https://stackoverflow.com/a/2550799/560648

Comment: `std::vector<T>::size()` returns `std::vector<T>::size_type`, which is *probably* the same as `std::size_t`, but who knows really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what I am trying to do is write some code that has no warnings with all the casting warnings set (maybe this is optamisitic when cross compiling)

It's optimistic when cross compiling if you have casts.

> Is there a good approach to this so that I dont get warnings on either compilers?

Don't have casts. Make your variable be of type `std::size_t`.

> I was going to just remove the `-Wuseless-cast` option

That's the other option.

Comment: How is this an answer, this is more like a comment.

Comment: @nada You are mistaken. Comments are for requesting clarification. If you think you have a better answer, feel free to post it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Done.

Answer (score 2):

As [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) pointed out, `size_t` is an option, it should have an appropriate macro to make compilers happy, if you somehow don't want to use that - making your variable `auto` or `decltype(test_vect.size())` would be another option:

```cpp
auto size = test_vect.size();
```

or

```cpp
decltype(test_vect.size()) size = test_vect.size();
```

Comment: It's the same option, just more obfuscated.

Answer (score 1):

One argument that comes to mind is: Why does your size variable need to be `long unsigned` at all instead of `std::size_t`?

Just in case there is a compelling reason for that, how about (C++17):

```
long unsigned size;
if constexpr(sizeof(long unsigned)!=sizeof(std::size_t))
    size = static_cast<long unsigned>(...);
else
    size = ...;
```

Comment: Doubt that'll work as there's no dependent name in the condition

Comment: That is an interesting idea... maybe wrapped in a cast-like function... I think I am sold on just removing useless cast for the moment, thanks

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You are correct (and this answer's second half is wrong): https://godbolt.org/z/l9VlIC