# Understanding fwrite() behaviour

Tags: c

1. When I use `fwrite` to `stdout` it becomes undefined results?
2. What is the use of the `size_t count` argument in `fwrite` and `fread` function?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct test
{
   char str[20];
   int num;
   float fnum;
}; 

int main()
{
   struct test test1={"name",12,12.334};

   fwrite(&test1,sizeof(test1),1,stdout);

   return 0;
}
```

output:

```
 name                   XEA
 Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.180 s
 Press any key to continue.
```

And when i use fwrite for file

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>

 struct test
 {
  char str[20];
  int num;
  float fnum;
 };

 int main()
 {
 struct test test1={"name",12,12.334};
 FILE *fp;

 fp=fopen("test.txt","w");

 if(fp==NULL)
 {
   printf("FILE Error");
   exit(1);
 }

 fwrite(&test1,sizeof(test1),1,fp);

 return 0;
 }
```

The File also contains like this

```
 name                   XEA
```

1. Why is the output like this?
2. And when I put `size_t count` as 5, it also becomes undefined result. What is the purpose of this argument?

Comment: Writing binary data to stdout is not useful, use printf() instead.

Comment: And what is the use of "size_t count" argument

Comment: fwrite() does not know whether you pass a pointer to a single struct or an array of structs.  In the C language, an array passed as an argument to a function decays to a pointer to the first element.  Which is why fwrite() has a count argument, if you lie to it then you get nonsense.  Big lies cause a hard crash.

Comment: @srilakshmikanthanp, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: If you use `fwrite` then it is pretty certain that you should open the file with *binary* mode i.e. `"wb"`, `"rb"` etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the way that you're using it, `fwrite` is writing "binary" output, which is a byte-for-byte representation of your `struct test` as in memory.  This representation is *not* generally human-readable.

When you write

```
struct test test1 = {"name", 12, 12.334};
```

you get a structure in memory which might be represented like this (with all byte valuess in hexadecimal):

```
test1: str: 6e 61 6d 65 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
       num: 0c 00 00 00
      fnum: 10 58 45 41
```

Specifically: `0x6e`, `0x61`, `0x6d`, and `0x65` are the ASCII codes for the letters in `"name"`.  Your `str` array was size 20, so the string `name` is 0-terminated and then padded out with 15 more 0 characters.  `0x0c` is the hexadecimal representation of the number 12, and I'm assuming that type `int` is 32 bits or 4 bytes on your machine, so there are 3 more 0's there, also.  (Also I'm assuming your machine is "little endian", with the least-significant byte of a 4-byte quantity like `0x0000000c` coming first in memory.)  Finally, in the [IEEE-754 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) which your machine uses, the number 12.334 is represented in 32-bit single-precision floating point as `0x41455810`, which is again stored in the opposite order in memory.

So those 28 bytes (plus possibly some padding, which we won't worry about for now) are precisely the bytes that get written to the screen, or to your file.  The string "name" will probably be human-readable, but all the rest will be, literally, "[binary garbage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_file)".  It just so happens that three of the bytes making up the float number 12.334, namely `0x58`, `0x45`, and `0x41`, correspond in ASCII to the capital letters `X`, `E`, and `A`, so that's why you see those characters in the output.

Here's the result of passing the output of your program into a "[hex dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) utility:

```
 0  6e 61 6d 65 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   name............
16  00 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00  10 58 45 41               .........XEA
```

You can see the letters `name` at the beginning, and the letters `XEA` at the end, and all the 0's and other binary characters in between.

If you're on a Unix or Linux (or Mac OS X) system, you can use tools like [`od`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/od) or [`hexdump`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/hexdump) to get a hex dump similar to the one I've shown.

---

You asked about the "count" argument to `fwrite`.  `fwrite` is literally designed for writing out binary structures, just like you're doing.  Its function signature is

```
size_t fwrite(void *ptr, size_t sz, size_t n, FILE *fp);
```

As you know, `ptr` is a pointer to the data structure(s) you're writing, and `fp` is the file pointer you're writing it/them to.  And then you're saying you want to write `n` (or 'count') items, each of size `sz`.

You called

```
fwrite(&test1, sizeof(test1), 1, fp);
```

The expression `sizeof(test1)` gives the size of `test1` in bytes.  (It will probably be 28 or so, as I mentioned above.)  And of course you're writing one struct, so passing `sizeof(test1)` and `1` as `sz` and `n` is perfectly reasonable and correct.

It would also not be unreasonable or incorrect to call

```
fwrite(&test1, 1, sizeof(test1), fp);
```

Now you're telling `fwrite` to write 28 bytes, each of size 1.  (A byte is of course always size 1.)

One other thing about `fwrite` (as noted by @AnttiHaapala in a comment): when you're writing binary data to a file, you should specify the `b` flag when you open the file:

```
fp = fopen("test.txt", "wb");
```

---

Finally, if this isn't what you want, if you want human-readabe text output instead, then `fwrite` is not what you want here.  You could use something like

```
printf("str: %s\n", test1.str);
printf("num: %d\n", test1.num);
printf("fnum: %f\n", test1.fnum);
```

Or, to your file:

```
fprintf(fp, "str: %s\n", test1.str);
fprintf(fp, "num: %d\n", test1.num);
fprintf(fp, "fnum: %f\n", test1.fnum);
```