# size_t compatible type for FFI

Tags: c#, ffi

I'm writing C# bindings for a C library using `unsafe` code. I can't figure out how to represent a `size_t` that works in all cases:

- `System.[U]IntPtr` can't be used with [fixed-sized buffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers) (which I need), because they are whitelisted to only work with a few primitive types.
- Aliasing the type with `using Usize = System.Uint32/64` with compile time directives works, but a) breaks the portability of the resulting binary between architectures and b) I'd have to add the using block to everywhere that used the `Usize` type.

So, what is the correct way to write C bindings using `size_t`?

Comment: System.IntPtr is designed for exactly this purpose, what's the reason you can't use it exactly? I didn't understand the "can't be used with fixed-sized buffer" part.

Comment: @mtreit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers The API has fixed-sized arrays of `size_t` in its structures, but C#'s fixed-sized arrays are only allowed for certain types.

Comment: The `size_t` type is implementation defined.  It's typically an `int`, but it doesn't have to be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2550774/what-is-size-t-in-c

Comment: @Flydog57 I know what size_t is in C. I need a type that works with it in C#'s interop. Also saying size_t is an int is really awful when most computers today are 64-bit.

Comment: It's implementation defined.  What does your C implementation use?

Comment: @Flydog57 My particular implementation is irrelevant; the code needs to work on both 32 and 64 bit platforms.

Comment: If your 32-bit implementation uses a 32-bit `size_t` and your 64-bit implementation uses a 64-bit `size_t`, then use `IntPtr` or `UIntPtr` - they end up being the right size even though semantically they are wrong.  But, implementation-dependent code is, well, implementation dependent

Comment: @Flydog57 I know about (U)IntPtr and I addressed in the answer and the comments above yours why I cannot use them...

Comment: The best/official equivalent for size_t is IntPtr. Maybe you can workaround your fixed buffer issue using other tricks (or don't use fixed buffers/unsafe).

Comment: Are you checking OS and your arrays bigger than 4 Gig elements?

Answer (score 4):

The size_t varies depending on the platform and no C# equivalent. And [.Net](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jaredpar/pinvoke-with-32-and-64-bit-machines) states that

> Unfortunately there is no predefined solution for these types in .NET
> 2.0.  So one has to be devised.  The biggest issue is that you typically run the same .NET binary or 32 and 64 bit.  So we need a
> type whose size is determined at runtime based on hints from the
> platform.  Defining a type like this just isn’t possible with .NET.
> The best recourse is to define a fixed size type and a custom
> marshaler that will make the runtime size decision.

So using UIntPtr will be your only option by aliasing the type with using **Usize = System.Uint32/64**