Why if(-1 < 0) comparision fails in c (sometimes)?
I have size_t file_size; variable declared in my c file which will get -1 assigned to it later and then when I do
if(file_size < 0) {
  // do something
} else {
  printf("C is confusing\n");
}

output: C is confusing

but if I set my condition to
if(file_size == -1) {
  printf("C is easy\n");
} else {
  // do something
}

output: C is easy

Can someone please explain why there is even a remote chance that this could be happening. Thanks in advance!

size_t is unsigned. It can never be < 0.

size_t type is unsigned, so it can't have value of -1. When you compare it to -1, the actual -1 is converted to unsigned.

If you need it to be signed, use ssize_t instead.

@Shawn ssize_t is a POSIX artifact and not generally available.

@AndrewHenle Being POSIX makes it generally available.

@Shawn Yeah, no

What's the point of this code, anyway? How can a file have a negative size?

That's why size_t is unsigned -- nothing can have a negative size.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2551647/17823490

Both cases are related to the fact the size_t is unsigned, i.e. it can represent only non-negative values.
When you assign -1 to it you actually get the unsigned equivalent (bitwise) of it. Since most (if not practically all) systems use 2s complement to represent negative integers, you will get a value where all bits are 1. For example, on systems where size_t is 32-bit, it will be assigned the value 0xFFFFFFFF (32 1s in binary).
The 1st case:
Since it is unsigned it can never be < 0.
The 2nd case:
When you compare it to -1, the -1 is actually converted to unsigned value (all 1s in binary as explained above), and the equality is then feasible.
On a POSIX system (or similar), if you want to represent negative values properly, you can use ssize_t instead of size_t (it's the signed version of it).
It requires #include <sys/types.h>.
