# Does casting a pointer back and forth from size_t or uintptr_t break strict aliasing?

Tags: c, api-design, strict-aliasing

I'm proposing a change to a library whose public API currently looks like this:

```
typedef size_t enh;  /* handle */

int en_open(enh *handle)
{
    struct internal *e = malloc(...);
    *handle = (enh)e;
    return 0;
}

int en_start(enh handle)
{
    struct internal *e = (struct internal*)handle;
    return do_something(e);
}
```

Does this usage, casting back and forth to `size_t` break strict aliasing?

For the record, I'm proposing a typical opaque forward declaration of `struct internal` in the public API, as shown on [this Programmers.SE question about the same code](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/294761/60495).

Comment: Is `size_t` guaranteed to be wide enough to hold a pointer? I don't think so..

Comment: @EugeneSh. [Nope](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572099/size-t-is-pointer-size-in-practice).

Comment: Then it is not just about aliasing. Casting pointer to `size_t` may just truncate it.

Comment: Do not use `size_t`! The correct type would be `uintptr_t` (You should know that, why else would you mention it?)

Comment: Wouldn't `void *` be better for a generic/opaque pointer anyway? Or am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: @Kninnug `void*` is not good, because it makes type checking impossible. Think of what happens when you have two different handle types in your interface. If either one is `void*`, the compiler won't catch the error if the user mixes them up. With proper opaque pointers, the compiler will catch these errors.

Comment: @cmaster, how does using `uintptr_t` help for type checking? I am lost.

Comment: @JensGustedt It doesn't. That's why I suggest the use of proper opaque pointers instead of disguised, type-deleted pointers.

Comment: @cmaster, but still `void*` is much better than `uintptr_t` or any other integer type.

Comment: @JensGustedt Yes. Opaque pointers is better than `void*`, which is better than `uintptr_t`, which is better than `size_t`. Precisely in that order :-)

Comment: See also question [size_t vs intptr_t in C99](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1464174/)

Comment: @JonathonReinhart It would help if you clarify that the code snippet above illustrate the original coding style in that library, not your proposed change.

Comment: @rwong: the phrase _whose public API currently looks like_ does state that the shown code is the 'original' style.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Aliasing is about two pointers of different type being used to access the same bytes. This is not the case in your code. When you access the data members behind the handle, you always do it via a pointer of type `struct internal*`. So no harm here.

The only questionable thing in your code is, that you are using `size_t` to pass the pointer. Afaik, the standard does not guarantee that you can safely cast a pointer to `size_t` and back, even though any sane implementation will allow it. The correct integer type choice would be `uintptr_t`, but you don't even need that:

I think, you should just use an opaque pointer in the interface. I. e., just put the declaration

```
typedef struct internal internal;
```

into your public header and keep the corresponding

```
struct internal {
    ...
}
```

private (replacing `internal` with a sensible public name, of course). The public functions can then simply be declared as:

```
int en_open(internal** outHandle);
int en_close(internal* handle);
```

That way, you get perfect type checking in the client code, and avoid the need for any casts.

Comment: `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to cast forth and back from/to a pointer to an object. However, you are right to avoid casting where possible.

Comment: @Olaf Yes, of course, I ignored that in my first draft because the cast to integer is not needed, so I didn't see a need to point out the correct integer type to cast to as well. I added a note about `uintptr_t` now, though.

Comment: @Olaf `uintptr_t` is guaranteed to cast forth and back from/to a `void *`.  Sure that works with any "pointer to an object"?

Comment: @chux: I left out the intermediate step for brevity: [6.3.2.3p1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.3p1). If you want to be safe, you can cast twice. It does work without for gcc-arm-none-eabi (with most warnings enabled), however. And if I look at paragraphs 5 and 6, the cast itself is also fine to me. (NOte that in C functions are **no** objects).